# Chrome experimental USB api does not find any device connected

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to develop a chrome extension using the USB experimental api. I never managed to find my usb device connected. My starting point for this extension is this code:
[knob example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/usb/knob)
I changed the vid and pid to match my usb device but without any success. I tried on Windows with both canary and the dev channel.

Seeing that I had no result, I modified the manifest to:

```
{
    "name": "USB Spinner",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "app.window",
        "experimental",
        "usb"
    ]
}
```

I added the experimental ans usb field in permissions. But still no results.

My code to access the USB device is:

```
var VENDOR_ID = 0x1234;
var PRODUCT_ID = 0x0006;

var usb = chrome.experimental.usb;

var deviceOptions = {
    onEvent: function(usbEvent) {
    }
};

usb.findDevice(
    VENDOR_ID,
    PRODUCT_ID,
    deviceOptions,
    function(device) {
        if (!device) {
            console.log('device not found');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Found device: ' + device.handle);
    }
);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you enabled experimental APIs at `chrome://flags`?

Comment: Yes the experimental extension is enabled

Comment: @samux, your manifest is correct. Some devices cannot be accessed directly, because the OS kernel grab and interpret them before the user space code has a chance to do it (for example, HID devices in MacOSX). Chromium USB support is based on libusb (1.0.8 on current Canary). If you want to test if your device should be visible for your Chrome app, you can test with any libusb-based client.

Comment: BTW, if you want to post the vendorID and productID, it's easier to help you.

Comment: I developed my own USB device (vid = 0x1234 and pid = 0x0006). It's a HID device. I am able to send and read data to and from the device using pyUSB with libusb (1.2.6) as backend. I also tried with a USB stick (vid = 0x13FE and pid = 0x1D00) without success.

Comment: Hi...Did you managed to get this working? I also developed some device using v-usb and atmega, and managed to get it work with visual studio. Now I wanted to try to write something for google chrome, but I also got device not found. My vids and pids are USB\VID_16C0&PID_05DC\5&255987D3&0&2... I suppose I have to write only POWERMATE_VENDOR_ID = 0x16C0 and POWERMATE_PRODUCT_ID = 0x05DC. Also I did not install edubeat drivers...please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

As mangini says, `chrome.usb` cannot access HID-class devices because the underlying operating system acquires them before that API implementation gets a chance. Fortunately, we're fixing that. Follow [the tracking bug for adding USB HID support](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305300) and please provide feedback on the suitability of the API and the quality of the implementation.